# EF Core 7.0.7 generates wrong SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0, ef-core-7.0

EF Core generates this query

```sql
SELECT TOP(1) [t].[TemplateId], [t].[Active], [t].[AssociatedYear], [t].[Deleted], [t].[FinalSummaryScreenId], [t].[FirstScreenId], 
[t].[IntermediateSummaryScreenId], [t].[Name], [t].[NameResourceId], [t].[PdfDocumentDocumentId], [t].[TemplateTypeId], [r].[ResourceId]
FROM [taxtool].[Templates] AS [t]
LEFT JOIN [taxtool].[Resources] AS [r] ON [t].[NameResourceId] = [r].[ResourceId]
WHERE [t].[TemplateId] = @__templateId_0
ORDER BY [t].[TemplateId], [r].[ResourceId]
```

from this code:

```cs
public async Task<Template?> GetTemplate(int templateId)
{
    return await Context.Templates
        .Where(t => t.TemplateId == templateId)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

the modelbuilder looks like this:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Template>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("Templates", "test");

    entity.HasKey(e => e.TemplateId).HasName("PK_Templates");

    entity.Property(e => e.Name)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(100);

    entity.HasOne(d => d.FinalSummaryScreen)
        .WithMany(p => p.FinalSummaryTemplates)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.FinalSummaryScreenId)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_Templates_Screens_FinalSummaryScreen");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.FirstScreen)
        .WithMany(p => p.FirstScreenTemplates)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.FirstScreenId)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_Templates_Screens_FirstScreen");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.IntermediateSummaryScreen)
        .WithMany(p => p.IntermediarySummeryTemplates)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.IntermediateSummaryScreenId)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_Templates_Screens_IntermediateSummaryScreen");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.NameResource)
        .WithMany(p => p.TemplateNames)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.NameResourceId)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_Templates_Resources_Name");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.TemplateType)
        .WithMany(p => p.Templates)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.TemplateTypeId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_Templates_TemplateType");

    entity.Navigation(e => e.NameResource).AutoInclude();
});
```

and my entity like this:

```cs
public class Template
{
    public int TemplateId { get; set; }
    public int TemplateTypeId { get; set; }
    public int? FirstScreenId { get; set; }
    public int? IntermediateSummaryScreenId { get; set; }
    public int? FinalSummaryScreenId { get; set; }
    public required string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public int? NameResourceId { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public int AssociatedYear { get; set; }

    public TemplateType? TemplateType { get; set; }
    public Screen? FirstScreen { get; set; }
    public Screen? IntermediateSummaryScreen { get; set; }
    public Screen? FinalSummaryScreen { get; set; }
    public Resource? NameResource { get; set; }
}
```

The issue now is that the sql query contains this `[t].[PdfDocumentDocumentId]` that does not exist in the entity nor the modelbuilder, nor the database, which then leads to an `SqlException: Invalid column name 'PdfDocumentDocumentId'` exception. None of the foreign key relations has anything remotely to do with this ID either and as seen in the query the [t] alias is used for Templates table, which again has nothing similar configured.

for completion sake, here are the modelbuilder configs for the many-to-many relation between Templates & PdfDocuments:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<TemplatePdfDocumentMapping>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("TemplatePDFMapping", "test");

    entity.HasKey(e => new { e.TemplateId, e.PdfDocumentId }).HasName("PK_TemplatePDFMapping");

    entity.Property(e => e.PdfDocumentId).HasColumnName("DocumentId");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.Template)
        .WithMany(p => p.PdfDocumentMappings)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.TemplateId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_TemplatePDFMapping_Template");

    entity.HasOne(d => d.PdfDocument)
        .WithMany(p => p.TemplateMappings)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.PdfDocumentId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_TemplatePDFMapping_Document");
});

modelBuilder.Entity<PdfDocument>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("PDFDocument", "test");

    entity.HasKey(e => e.DocumentId).HasName("PK_PDFDocument");

    entity.Property(e => e.Label)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(160);

    entity.HasOne(d => d.Folder)
        .WithMany(p => p.PdfDocuments)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.FolderId)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_PDFDocument_Folder");
});
```

Comment: Is there a `PdfDocument` class that has a navigation property of type `Template`? If so, I would double check the configuration on that class to make sure it's specifying the correct FK

Comment: Are there any classes that inherit from `Template` ? Eg a `PdfDocumentTemplate` or `PdfDocument` class?  EF Core wouldn't come up with `PdfDocumentDocumentId` out of thin air. In EF Core 7 join tables are created automatically, eg if you have a Blog.Posts property and a Post class, EF Core will generate the BlogPosts table automatically. The name `PdfDocumentDocumentId` looks suspiciously like an attempt to read from the join table of PdfDocument and Document.

Comment: @Luke, the is a class PdfDocument, but it has no direct realtion with Template

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no the Template class is never inherited. I agree that the name looks suspisously like an auto-generated relation key, but i checked mutliple times already and can't find any entity that might create this

Comment: We can't guess what your code looks like. Post enough code to reproduce the problem. In fact, isolating the entities needed to reproduce the problem may actually solve it.

Answer (score -1):

After a bunch of digging i found the issue: the PdfDoument entity still contained some legacy navigation property of the style `public ICollection<Template> Templates { get; set;}` which in turn prompted EF to generate a shadow FK for this. I was just looking at the wrong entity when debuuging x(